# No matching distribution found for socketserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, websocket, serversocket

I tried to import socketserver and it asked me to install, so i went with the command "pip install socketserver" and it says: 
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement socketserver (from versions:) 
No matching distribution found for socketserver"

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: that mean socketserver Package Dont Exist On Pip

Answer (score 4):

`socketserver` is a standard library module so you don't need to install it. It looks like you are using Python 2 so use `SocketServer`, In Python 3 it's renamed to `socketserver`.